# Selenium chromedriver no longer opens command prompt

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I'm not sure what I've done but all off the sudden my selenium stopped opening the command prompt when opening with the browser..

I've tried setting
 `driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = false;`

but that didn't seem to work! I really need the cmd to open as I use it for cleanup!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This may not solve your problem, but... `HideCommandPromptWindow` should definitely be set to `false`.  `Hide=true` will hide the window, not show it!

Comment: I did have it set to false in my actual code but ty for correction on the question

Answer (score 0):

Today GoogleChrome updted maybe if you download the last version of chrome driver:

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads